# Heroku Static files not working for django admin + File Not found + 404

Tags: django, heroku, django-admin

My site is deployed on Heroku. Everything is going good except static files.
Static files are there on this path `doctor_app/doctor_app/static/`.

Locally, Admin panel for django is working perfectly. But on heroku, It doesn't find any static files.

Surprisingly when i run this command with terminal.

```
heroku run cat doctor_app/static/admin/css/base.css
```

It outputs the content of `base.css`. which means static files are there

I wonder why django is not finding any files ?

For more info, Here is my `settings.py`

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
#STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles'),
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Did you execute "python manage.py collectstatic"?

Comment: Yes I did. @VijeshVenugopal

Comment: @AdilMalik by "it doesn't find any static files" do you mean that they return a 404 error? If so, how are you linking to those static files in your template? Also, please post your `settings.py` variables for static files, e.g., `STATICFILES_DIRS`, etc.

Comment: Yes, I am getting 404 error. And i have edited the question. Please have a look @YPCrumble

Comment: @AdilMalik you still need to show how you're linking to these static files in your template, i.e., what piece of html is generating the 404 error, what is the URL path it's pointing to, and how is it implemented in the template?

Comment: I am not using it in templates. I am trying to access admin panel provided by django. @YPCrumble

Comment: @AdilMalik did you determine whether the issue is due to your `STATICFILES_STORAGE` setting per [this part of the docs](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#troubleshooting-the-whitenoise-storage-backend)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a Django error. What Django does is getting static files ready and collect them into `STATIC_ROOT`, which is all set in your case.

Be aware that serving static files for a Django project is not typically within its responsibility. You can refer to [Django's doc on deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/deployment/) and try to deploy them using apps like `uwsgi` or `nginx`.

For a quick try, you can append static files into Django's routing, as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

As far as your question has provided, this could work for you.

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thank you

Comment: Note : apending `static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` will not work if `DEBUG=False`. Mentioned clearly in the Note section of Doc : `This helper function works only in debug mode`

Answer (score 3):

Django does not support serving static files in production. However, the fantastic WhiteNoise project can integrate into your Django application, and was designed with exactly this purpose in mind.

See the WhiteNoise documentation for more details.

Installing Whitenoise

First, install WhiteNoise with pip:

```
pip install whitenoise
```

Be sure to add whitenoise to your requirements.txt file as well.

Next, install WhiteNoise into your Django application. This is done in settings.py’s middleware section (at the top):

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # Simplified static file serving.
    # https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
...
```

Finally, if you’d like gzip functionality enabled, also add the following setting to settings.py.

settings.py

## Simplified static file serving.

## https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Your application will now serve static assets directly from Gunicorn in production. This will be perfectly adequate for most applications, but top-tier applications may want to explore using a CDN with Django-Storages.

Collectstatic during builds
When a Django application is deployed to Heroku, $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput is run automatically during the build. A build will fail if the collectstatic step is not successful.

Debugging
If collectstatic failed during a build, a traceback was provided that will be helpful in diagnosing the problem. If you need additional information about the environment collectstatic was run in, use the DEBUG_COLLECTSTATIC configuration.

```
heroku config:set DEBUG_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

This will display in your build output all of the environment variables that were available to Python when the collectstatic command was executed.

Disabling Collectstatic
Sometimes, you may not want Heroku to run collectstatic on your behalf. You can disable the collectstatic build step with the DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC configuration:

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

This will fully disable the collectstatic step of the build.